# Error message - AdvanceToElement:unable to find xml element

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, xml, arccatalog

How can I handle the below error when I'm trying to add an XML file into ArcGIS for Desktop using ArcCatalog.

> AdvanceToElement:Unable to find XML element (WorkspaceDefinition not found in XML doc)

XML files are provided by the client as a reference files to attach in our ArcMap, this is fist time we are using XML in ArcMap. Our ArcMap version is 10.1.

Please, remember that I'm very new to using xml files in arcmap.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?> 
- <INVENTORY>
- <ATTACHMENT>
  <REF_TYPE>NONE</REF_TYPE> 
  <ANCILLARYROLE>0</ANCILLARYROLE> 
  <ATTACHMENT_NAME>SLACK:FIB::961</ATTACHMENT_NAME> 
  <ATTACHMENT_REF_NAME>20m</ATTACHMENT_REF_NAME> 
  <CATEGORY_NAME>SLACK-E</CATEGORY_NAME> 
  <ENABLED>1</ENABLED> 
  <INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE>IPL</INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE> 
  <LENGTH_ADJUSTMENT>20</LENGTH_ADJUSTMENT> 
  <MODEL_UUID>{2937E405-1E38-42F9-991B-4AAA4A6DED77}</MODEL_UUID> 
  <MODIFICATION_IND>0</MODIFICATION_IND> 
  <Q_CREATE_WORK_ORDER>TCA_10_4_base_data</Q_CREATE_WORK_ORDER> 
  <REF_UUID>{5E60CBAE-C234-4A1A-B132-4CAC48AF1FC4}</REF_UUID> 
  <ROTATION>0</ROTATION> 
  <GEOMETRY>X="230483.90725" Y="395726.049"</GEOMETRY> 
  <TRANSMEDIA_NAME>FIB-Q:48F::6406</TRANSMEDIA_NAME> 
  <TYPE_NAME>FIBER</TYPE_NAME> 
  <UUID>{ACBBDD7D-1DA1-4F75-84BB-803DB4B04C9B}</UUID> 
  </ATTACHMENT>
- <ATTACHMENT>
  <REF_TYPE>NONE</REF_TYPE> 
  <ANCILLARYROLE>0</ANCILLARYROLE> 
  <ATTACHMENT_NAME>SLACK:FIB::962</ATTACHMENT_NAME> 
  <ATTACHMENT_REF_NAME>20m</ATTACHMENT_REF_NAME> 
  <CATEGORY_NAME>SLACK-E</CATEGORY_NAME> 
  <ENABLED>1</ENABLED> 
  <INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE>IPL</INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE> 
  <LENGTH_ADJUSTMENT>20</LENGTH_ADJUSTMENT> 
  <MODEL_UUID>{2937E405-1E38-42F9-991B-4AAA4A6DED77}</MODEL_UUID> 
  <MODIFICATION_IND>0</MODIFICATION_IND> 
  <Q_CREATE_WORK_ORDER>TCA_10_4_base_data</Q_CREATE_WORK_ORDER> 
  <REF_UUID>{5E60CBAE-C234-4A1A-B132-4CAC48AF1FC4}</REF_UUID> 
  <ROTATION>0</ROTATION> 
  <GEOMETRY>X="230583.2762" Y="395795.57475"</GEOMETRY> 
  <TRANSMEDIA_NAME>FIB-Q:48F::6406</TRANSMEDIA_NAME> 
  <TYPE_NAME>FIBER</TYPE_NAME> 
  <UUID>{6BB5FB19-B6A5-4DC0-8657-F5B1D76F1757}</UUID> 
  </ATTACHMENT>
  </INVENTORY>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you figured this out yet I am having the same problem

Comment: This isn't an answer. If you want to add a comment, please do so below the question.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: If the file which you tried to import was actually an XMI file, then since XMI files appear in Windows with the .xml file extension, it is easy to make this mistake with them.

Answer (score 1):

You have made the incorrect assumption that all [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) is created equal. XML is a [markup language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language), not a strictly-defined data exchange format, and can contain practically anything. The software that reads the XML needs to know what to do with its contents. In this case, the software (ArcGIS) does not understand the contents of your XML file.

The reason for the error is *not* that no XML schema ([XSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_%28W3C%29)) file is present, but that you are simply doing something that is not supported by the software.

[XML Workspace Documents](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00050000000n000000) are an ESRI-designed "flavor" of XML specifically intended for the exchange ESRI geodatabases. ArcGIS knows how to read and write these files, but only if they are in the expected format.

Since your XML data is *not* an ESRI XML Workspace document, you will have to come up with a different solution. What you use depends on what you need to do with the data (please elaborate), but one possibility that comes to mind might be to use Python (using one of the many available XML libraries such as [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) or [lxml](http://lxml.de/)) to read the XML file contents and create a table or feature class with [arcpy](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v000000v7000000).

A more direct solution might be to ask your client to deliver the data in a format ArcGIS can work with out of the box.